# Making a table using the grid function with some modifications

Tags: grid-layouts, frame

I am trying to make a table out of some formulas which I listed in the code section, however, I am having several issues:

*Alignment of rows (I think it has something to do with scientific notation since those values are the only ones not aligned, but I may be mistaken).

*Headers proper alignment, e.g. $N_B$ should span $q_B$ and $\Omega_B$ only

*Frames on all items (I know why the elements in the column of say, $q_A$ are not framed, it is because I declared the whole column as a "single object" so "Frame -> All" framed the whole column, but I don't know how to modify this).

```
q1 = Column[Table[i, {i, 0, 20}]];
q2 = Column[Reverse[Table[i, {i, 480, 500}]]];
\[CapitalOmega]1[q1_] := (q1 + 1 - 1)!/(q1! (1 - 1)!)
\[CapitalOmega]2[q2_] := (q2 + 100 - 1)!/(q2! (100 - 1)!)
\[CapitalOmega] = Column[Times[Table[\[CapitalOmega]1[q1], {q1, 0, 20}], Reverse[Table[N[\[CapitalOmega]2[q2]], {q2, 480, 500}]]]];
Ln\[CapitalOmega] = Column[Log[Times[Table[\[CapitalOmega]1[q1], {q1, 0, 20}], Reverse[Table[N[\[CapitalOmega]2[q2]], {q2, 480, 500}]]]]];
m1 = Column[Table[ScientificForm[\[CapitalOmega]1[q1]], {q1, 0, 20}]];
m2 = Column[Reverse[Table[ScientificForm[N[\[CapitalOmega]2[q2]]], {q2, 480, 500}]]];
Grid[{{"Two Einstein Solid", SpanFromLeft}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(A\)]\)=1", SpanFromLeft, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(B\)]\)=100", SpanFromLeft}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(A\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalOmega]\), \(A\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(B\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalOmega]\), \(B\)]\)", "\[CapitalOmega]"}, {q1, m1, q2, m2, \[CapitalOmega]}}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemSize -> {{Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.1], Scaled[0.1]}}, Spacings -> {2, 2}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Problem 6.1]

*Please be as basic as possible and can someone explain each function clearly.

Comment: Do you get what you need if you use  `Join[{{"Two Einstein Solid", SpanFromLeft}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(A\)]\)=1",  SpanFromLeft, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(B\)]\)=100",     SpanFromLeft, ""}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(A\)]\)",   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalOmega]\), \(A\)]\)",  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(B\)]\)",  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalOmega]\), \(B\)]\)",  "\[CapitalOmega]"}}, {q1, m1, q2, m2, \[CapitalOmega]} /.  Column -> Identity // Transpose]` as the first argument in `Grid`?

Comment: @kglr Indeed! Can you please explain a bit why that must be the case with those functions? What are my mistakes? Also, the alignment of $N_B$ is not yet resolved.

Comment: mathemania, your code give as a table with 5 columns (your picture has 6). For 6 columns, change `""` after the last `SpanFromLeft` to `"", SpanFromLeft`.

Comment: @kglr That fixed the $N_B$ problem, but can you say something about why you chose to write $Join$ and $/. Column -> Identity // Transpose$ in order to fix my problem, what are their purposes in this context?

Comment: `{q1, m1, q2, m2, \[CapitalOmega]} /. Column -> Identity` removes the `Column` so that you end up with a matrix with 5 rows and 21 columns; `Transpose` converts that  5X21 matrix into a 21X5 matrix. `Join` just appends this matrix to your list of header rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the options `Alignment -> Center` and `ItemSize -> {All, 2}` to `Column` when you define `q1`, `m1`, `q2`, `m2` and `Ω`, e.g.

```
q1 = Column[Table[i, {i, 0, 20}], Alignment -> Center, ItemSize -> {All, 2}];
```

Then the rows in each `Column` object are aligned:

```
Grid[{{"Two Einstein Solid", 
   SpanFromLeft}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(A\)]\)=1", 
   SpanFromLeft, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(B\)]\)=100", 
   SpanFromLeft, ""}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(A\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Ω\), \(A\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(B\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Ω\), \(B\)]\)", 
   "Ω"}, {q1, m1, q2, m2, Ω}}, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
 ItemSize -> {{Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.15],
     Scaled[0.15]}}, Spacings -> {2, 2}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

where I added `""` after the last `SpanFromLeft` so that $N_B = 100$ spans only two columns.

With this approach you can not add divider lines aligned across columns.

A better approach is to remove `Column` from  `{q1, m1, q2, m2, Ω}` and `Transpose` the resulting 5X21 matrix into a 21X5 matrix and append it to the header rows

```
mat = Join[{{"Two Einstein Solid", 
    SpanFromLeft}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(A\)]\)=1", 
    SpanFromLeft, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(B\)]\)=100", 
    SpanFromLeft, ""}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(A\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Ω\), \(A\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(B\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Ω\), \(B\)]\)", "Ω"}}, 
   Transpose[{q1, m1, q2, m2, Ω} /. Column -> Identity]];
```

and use `mat` as the first argument in `Grid`:

```
Grid[mat, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
 ItemSize -> {{Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.15],
     Scaled[0.15]}}, Spacings -> {2, 2}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]